Projection of world map (Northern Hemisphere part) in R (Arctic Polar Stereographic)
I want to plot a polar projected Northern Hemisphere map (Arctic Polar Stereographic,EPSG:3995) using ggplot2 in R, where the basemap extent needs to be above 20 degrees north latitude.But the map always fails to display correctly after changing the projection. I've checked multiple projections but can't find the problem.
this is my attempt
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
worldmap <- ne_countries(scale = 'medium', type = 'map_units',
                         returnclass = 'sf')
worldmap_trans <- st_transform(worldmap, st_crs(3995))
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = worldmap)
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = worldmap_trans)



Based on this GIS Stack Exchange post, using coord_sf() with sf::st_crs("ESRI:102016") does what I think you are looking for and works with either projection of world map.
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = worldmap)+
  coord_sf(crs = sf::st_crs("ESRI:102016"))

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = worldmap_trans)+
  coord_sf(crs = sf::st_crs("ESRI:102016"))


The OP has sf loaded, so you can simplify to coord_sf(crs = "ESRI:102016"). And in the case of conformal CRS e.g. WGS84/EPSG:4326, quotes are not needed e.g. coord_sf(crs = 4326).

Awesome, perfect! the question has been resolved
